# How to avoid admin.E111 error in Django 1.9.2?

Tags: python, django, hyperlink, django-admin, nonetype

Up until Django 1.8.x I had this code in my `admin.py` file:

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_display = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClassAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.list_display_links = (None, )
```

This was meant to disable the link on the rows of the Model when the users opened it. I need this because this refers to a read-only table and I don't want users to be able to even edit entries.

Recently, I upgraded to Django 1.9.2, and this code is currently returning an error:

> django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System
> check identified some issues:
>
> ERRORS: <class 'myapp.admin.MyClassAdmin'>: (admin.E111) The value of
> 'list_display_links[0]' refers to 'None', which is not defined in
> 'list_display'.

As per the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/checks/), this is:

> admin.E111: The value of list_display_links[n] refers to , which is not defined in list_display.

This is quite vague and doesn't explain how to handle non-string values such as `None`.

How can I modify this piece of code so I can overwrite the `list_display_links` attribute in the `__init__` function?

Comment: It says it cannot make a link for an item that is not specified in `list_display` - What are you trying to do ? You should not specify `None` as a linkable item anyways..

Comment: Maybe a hacky way, but this disabled the link to edit an entry in the model view inside the Django Admin. So it prints "plain" entries in the list and avoids users modifying the entries.

Comment: Just remove the tuple.. `self.list_display_links = None` should work

Comment: Yep, this solved it. I understand this is a consistency check, I don't know why is not `None` a valid value here. Anyway, would you mind adding a short answer with this so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: Alasdair's answer is pretty comprehensive. Please go ahead and accept that as the answer. Me answering would not be any different from that anyways..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs for [`list_display_links`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links) say that you should use `None` if you do not want to display any links. You are returning a tuple, which means that Django expects each item in the tuple to be a field in `list_display`. Since `None` is not a field, you get the error from the checks framework.

As an aside, it's not recommended to set `self.list_display_links` in the model admin's `__init__` method. It would be better to set `list_display_links` on the class.

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
    list_display_links = None
```

Or, if you need to change it dynamically, then override [`get_list_display_links`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links).

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')

    def get_list_display_links(request, list_display):
        if condition():
            return None
        else:
            return list_display
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `None` instead of `(None, )` to `self.list_display_links` as shown below:

```py
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_display = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClassAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.list_display_links = (None, )
        self.list_display_links = None
                                 # ↑ Here
```

And, you will get the same error if assigning `(None, )` to [list_display_links](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links) as shown below:

```py
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_display = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
    list_display_links = (None, ) # Here
```

So, you should assign `None` instead of `(None, )` to `list_display_links` as shown below:

```py
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_display = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
    # list_display_links = (None, )
    list_display_links = None
                        # ↑ Here
```

In addition, I got the similar error below:

> ERRORS: <class 'store.admin.PersonAdmin'>: (admin.E111) The value of
> 'list_display_links[1]' refers to 'last_name', which is not defined in
> 'list_display'.

When `"last_name"` is not assigned to [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) but assigned to [list_display_links](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links) as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("first_name",)      # ↓ Here
    list_display_links = ("first_name", "last_name")
```

So, I assigned `"last_name"` to `list_display` then the error above was solved:

```py
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): # ↓ Here
    list_display = ("first_name", "last_name")      
    list_display_links = ("first_name", "last_name")
```